# How to automatically backup thousands of computer CDs and DVDs

Tags: backup

I have thousands of computer CDs and DVDs with some data. I want to backup them in an automated way (i.e. not change disc by disc by hand).

I found this so far:

- [Auto Ripper hackaday project](https://hackaday.io/project/11836-auto-ripper-bddvd-changer-for-automated-ripping)
- [Vinpower RipBox station](https://www.vinpowerdigital.com/main/product.aspx?CategoryID=51&Keyword=RipBox) (expensive)
- [Nimbie Disc Autoloader](http://www.nimbie.com/cd-dvd-autoloader-ripper-overview.html#data) (via [davidgo](https://superuser.com/users/137786/davidgo) [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1391183/how-to-automatically-backup-thousands-of-computer-cds-and-dvds?noredirect=1#comment2098177_1391183)) (extremely expensive)
- [DIY autoloader hackaday project](https://hackaday.com/2013/10/05/diy-cd-autoloader/) ([original German source](http://www.hackerspace-ffm.de/wiki/index.php?title=DIY-Autoloader#.2F), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U8RGKXI6t0), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6toB3w7e_Q))

Are these the only options? What other options are there?
Maybe just a regular DVD drive + a robot arm?
("autoloader" seems to be a good search term, better than "disc changer" what I used initially.)

(Not sure if this is the right StackExchange site to ask. Please, before voting to close, please at least give me an advice where to ask instead. On [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1391183/how-to-automatically-backup-thousands-of-computer-cds-and-dvds) it was suggested to ask here.)

Comment: What kind of data is on the disks?

Comment: @JMY1000 Anything, really. Those are backups from old PCs, programming projects, music, pictures, etc. But this should not matter really.